# Speed of csv reading slow python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to find a cause of slow CSV reading.

I tried multiple approaches, I have 8GB csv file, after processing it is around 6GB with 10 columns.

What I was thinking is, reading the file with one thread and then processing it in another one, so I do not use any bandwith. basically apporach I found in another stack overflow thread.

The speed now is around 1112 second for reading the file only! Which equals to around 7MB/s. I can get reading speed on this drive through SQL to around 380 MB/s, so there must be some bottleneck or some other thing.

I am not worried about processing or some other stuff. I am just interested in reading the file into memory ASAP and then processing it. There probably some issue with my code, because pandas is way way faster (althoug not anyway near the disk speed), see at the bottom.

Maybe thats how it is, but I am not happy with that.

```
import os, csv, time, math
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

file = r'local_disk_file.csv'
out = r'network_location'
_sentinel = object()

def convert10(x10, y10):
    # some processing

    return gridcellid10



def read_file(file, q):
    start = time.monotonic()

    with open(file, 'r', newline='') as inFile:
        next(inFile)
        for row in inFile:
            q.put(row)

    q.put(_sentinel)
    print('File read in {}s'.format(time.monotonic()-start))


def post_process(in_q):
    with open(os.path.join(out, "output_on_network.csv"), 'w', newline='') as outFile:
        writer = csv.writer(outFile)
        row = ['AreaID', 'CellID', 'Case1', 'Case2', 'Case3', 'Case4', 'Case5', 'Case6', 'Case7', 'Case8']
        writer.writerow(row)
        for row in iter(in_q.get, _sentinel):
            reader = csv.reader([row])
            for row in reader:
                cellid = convert10(int(row[1]), int(row[2]))
                final_row = [row[0], cellid]

                switch = False
                for item in row[6:]:
                    if int(item) > 15000:
                        switch = True
                        print('Broken row, skipping')
                        print('\t' + ' '.join(row))
                final_row.extend(row[6:])
                if not switch:
                    writer.writerow(final_row)


def main():
    q = Queue()
    t1 = Thread(target=read_file, args=(file, q))
    t2 = Thread(target=post_process, args=(q,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to use pandas and that is way faster. The below code takes around 92 seconds, which equals to roughly 81 MB/s.

```
import pandas as pd, time


file = r'local_disk_file.csv'

start = time.monotonic()
df = pd.read_csv(file)
print(time.monotonic()-start)
```

Edit: I also tried just reading and doing nothing with the file. That takes 45s which equals to 177 MB/s, which I am happy with.

```
import time


file = r'local_disk_fileL.csv'

start = time.monotonic()
with open(file, 'r', newline='') as in_file:
    for row in in_file:
        pass
print(time.monotonic()-start)
```

Comment: You are using the `csv` module wrong... in fact your code is broken and will not be able to parse valid CSVs (basically any CSV that contains a newline in a quoted field). You are supposed to create only one `csv.reader` passing the file object as argument, and you should put the rows obtained from the `csv.reader` in the queue. Right now your code contains a  big overhead of creating a new csv reader for every single row of the file.

Comment: Also: python standard library provides utilies for most common usages. Parsing 8GB CSV files is not common and thus the standard `csv` module is not optimized to handle that. If you are dealing with huge files or other peculiar requirement chances are you want to look a specialized library to deal with that (but this is true for all languages & standard libraries basically... )

Comment: I understand, but i wanted to not use any function for the file reader. Just let the other thread handle that. I only wanted to read line and pass it to another function, which will take care of the rest.

Comment: Creating many one time use objects in an loop is an great to keep GC busy. Also you threading may dosen't really help because of the GIL and the relativ low amount of work done. So basically you add some context switch for nearly no parallel processing.

Comment: Okay, that seems reasonable. Well, is there some other way to process it in another thread/process which will not block GIL?

Comment: Why do you think  threading will be necessary or useful? Just read one line, process it, and write it. Unless the processing overhead is huge (in which  case, optimize that) your I/O latency is going to dominate over the processing anyway, and adding parallelism only adds overhead.

Comment: That was the first approach, which unfortunately does not save any time. Maybe i get it wrong. What i thoguh was, load the file into memory asap and then read it from there (which should be very fast) and process it and write it to different drive.I am doing some simple math calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the best option for me is reading it through pandas and then apply parallel processing. This way I am able to achieve reading speed of 65 MB/s. It is not anywhere near max speed of the drive. But it considerably speeds up my problem.

Also a good option is to read csv, save is as parquet file and work with that. That way, we can save a lot of space and the read speed is very fast, because it is reading the file in parallel, the more columns the better speed!

Also if we read the csv, process it and save it as parquet, I can get a very big speed up.

With conversion to parquet and processing it an writing it back as parquet file, I can process the whole file in around 140s. If I read the csv with pandas,the reading only takes the same amount of time and another bottleneck is writing the file back to disk.

This means for me, stop using the csv files!

```
import time, math, pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

file = r'in_parquet.pqt'
out = r'out_parquet.pqt'


def gridcellid(x, y, xmin, ymin, xshift, yshift, m, n, r, mtidshift):
    ## some processing
    return gridcellid

def read(file):
    start = time.monotonic()
    df = pd.read_parquet(file, engine = 'pyarrow')
    print(f'File read in {time.monotonic()-start}s')
    return df

def calculate(df):


    df['CellID'] = 0
    df['CellID'] = [gridcellid(x, y, 97170, 274320, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0) for x, y in zip(df['x'], df['y'])]


    cols = ['Domain', 'CellID', 'RP00005', 'RP00010', 'RP00050', 'RP00100', 'RP00200', 'RP00500', 'RP01000', 'RP10000']
    df.drop(columns = ['uwPop', 'uwInd', 'a01_5dPC', 'x', 'y'])
    df = df.reindex(columns=cols)
    df.rename({"Domain": "AreaID",  "RP00005": "Case1",
                             "RP00010": "Case2", "RP00050": "Case3", "RP00100": "Case4",
                             "RP00200": "Case5", "RP00500": "Case6", "RP01000" : "Case7", "RP10000" : "Case8"}, inplace=True)

    return df


def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=16):
    n = 100000
    df_split = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
    pool = mp.Pool(n_cores)
    li_df = []
    for i in pool.imap(func, df_split):
        li_df.append(i)
    df = pd.concat(li_df)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.monotonic()
    df_input = read(file)
    df_merged = parallelize_dataframe(df_input, calculate)
    df_merged.to_parquet(out, engine = 'pyarrow', index = False)
    print(f'File completely processed in {time.monotonic()-start}s')
```